# Nativescript-auth0 | java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, nativescript, auth0, tns

To begin with , i'm quite new with this so excuse me if i forgot some informations and already thanks for your help.

I'm trying to use nativescript-auth0 to login to my nativescript android app.

First , my tns version is 4.1.2.
The version of tns-android is 4.1.3.
The version of nativescript-auth0 is 2.0.0.

I followed this link : https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/nativescript-auth0

As they saied , i added to the Android Manifest :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.auth0.android.provider.RedirectActivity"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="jarggon.eu.auth0.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/org.nativescript.JarggonTranslatorApp/callback"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In my component i have :

```
 lock.show().then((res) => {
  console.log('success');
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

With my instance of lock , everything is perfectly fine.

But when i'm running the app by " tns run android " i get this :

> JS: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference JS:
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:102)
>   JS: com.auth0.android.lock.Lock.initialize(Lock.java:144) JS:
>   com.auth0.android.lock.Lock.access$200(Lock.java:56) JS:
>   com.auth0.android.lock.Lock$Builder.build(Lock.java:236) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946) JS:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
>   JS: android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7041) JS:
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032) JS:
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre...

I know it's from the console.log of the error in the lock.show() function , but i don't understand why..

I also tried to add a reference.d.ts file in the root and put in it :

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Lock.ios.d.ts" />
```

But i get something like 30 errors at runtime like :

> node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(2,43): error
>   TS2552: Cannot find name 'NSObject'. Did you mean 'Object'?
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(8,42): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURL'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(10,42): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURL'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(10,58): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURLSession'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(12,153): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSDictionary'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(12,195): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSError'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(12,208): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSDictionary'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(14,45): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURL'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(16,52): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURL'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(16,68): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSURLSession'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(18,118): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSDictionary'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(18,160): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSError'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(20,151): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSDictionary'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(20,193): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSError'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-auth0/typings/Auth0.ios.d.ts(22,93): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSError'.

I don't know what else i can do .. thanks for your help , if you need any information tell me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved. If someone need to know i had to use the loaded event of the GridLayout .. Because the view wasn't ready before i do the instance of the lock even if i used ngAfterViewInit .